# Why protected member is accessed by subclass of subclass of a class which are placed in different packages

Tags: java, oop

Why this code runs fine??

```
package certification;
public class Parent {
    protected int x = 9; // protected access
    protected void z(){System.out.println(5);}
}


package other;
import certification.Parent;
class C extends Parent{}
public class Child extends C {
    public void testIt() {
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
        this.z();
    }

}

import other.Child;
class Test extends Child{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Child().testIt();
    }
}
```

This gives output:

> x is 9
>
> 5

But how can `subclass(Child)` of `subclass(C)` can access protected member of class Parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the protected modifier mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637781/what-does-the-protected-modifier-mean)

Comment: Another link that might help you understand the difference between access modifiers in java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example class Child extends C and class C extends Parent. This means Child is a subclass of Parent. 
Protected fields are visible both to all subclasses and to classes in the same package. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html