# Selenium element not interactable with same id

Tags: java, selenium, testing, css-selectors

I have a base page class like this

```
public class BasePage{
    @FindBy(id = "select2-ccnl-container")
    protected WebElement ccnlSelect;

    public void clickSettingCcnl(){
        ccnlSelect.click();
    }
}
```

then i created 2 class `Page1` and `Page2` both extending `BasePage`.
those are 2 different pages containing an element with that id. When i use the `clickSettingCcnl()` in a test on `Page1` everything is ok.

But the same thing on `Page2` gave me `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`

The element is visible and clickable on `Page1` and so it seems on `Page2`.

Comment: visible != clickable

Comment: that's right i've updated the question, the item is exactly the same on the 2 pages i don't understand why they have different behaviour

Comment: Have you tried by using wait statements?

Comment: yes i did but i got the same exception

Comment: Make the `WebElement ccnlSelect` public or at least not protected.

Comment: More about `protected` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637781/what-does-the-protected-modifier-mean

Comment: Got it, it was an issue with a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with said id was inside another one, in `Page2` it had a class added dynamically that set its dimension to 0 but i didn't notice it because of the parent element hiding this transformation.

By removing that class it got back to a dimension > 0 and hence clickable by Selenium